# is it possible to create search prompts in solr similar to google search prompts?

Tags: solr, indexing, search-engine

i'd like to know if search prompts can be generated in solr, similar to those at google?

basically, the index generates phrases based on user-input,
Which solr modules should i be looking at?

example:
When the user enters "How to progra..."

The prompts of "How to program in c++", "how to program in php" etc.... appear below the search area

Comment: Can you give an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Solr have http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Suggester for this kind of stuff. Take a look at the example, it should help you.